# H1 tags vs H2 tags - Weight of content for SEO

Tags: html, seo

Is header tag content weighted differently when it comes to SEO?

For example if I were to replace my h1 elements with h2... 
(assuming only a single h2 elements per page and no other header elements )

1. Would this reduce optimization? Would the content be ranked lower?

Comment: Why do you want to replace the single h1 element on a page with a h2 element? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I don't want to do it at all...  I was in the process of changing someone's h3 elements to h1 elements when they tried to tell me it didn't make a difference.  I tried to find information regarding header elements weight vs other header elements and couldn't find a concrete answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is logical to assume that `<h1>` tags carry more weight then `<h2>` as typically the `<h1>`  is the title of the page and conveys the general subject matter of the content below. So switching from and `<h1>`  to an `<h2>` *should* reduce the value of your semantic markup and thus have a negative effect on your rankings. But since there are so many other factors involved in ranking pages, unless you're after a really long tail keyword I wouldn't expect it to make any noticeable difference.

If you are doing this because you prefer the style of an `<h2>` tag over an `<h1>`  tag then you are definitely making a mistake. You should use CSS to alter the appearance of the `<h1>` tag to suit your needs. This is perfectly fine to do from an SEO perspective as long as you aren't trying to make the `<h1>` tag look like normal text (which you aren't).

Comment: So it does matter, but in terms of overall ranking it may only make a small difference.  Thank you for confirming for me that the element difference does matter.